# How to align rendered cell rows to the right?

Tags: css, gwt

I have a `CellTable` with `Columns`. One of the column I align the text to the right programatically:

```
column.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

Further I want the cell to have a padding on the right. By cannot get it to work. This is what I tried:

```
column.setCellStyleNames("numberCell");

.numberCell {
  padding-right: 5px !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

The text in the cell is rendered in red, but there is no padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you applied style it should work. but let You try apply particular column style using `getCellStyleNames`. it may work.

```
Column<Data,String> noColumn=new Column<Data, String>(new TextCell()) {
             @Override
            public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, Data  object) {
                  return "numberCell";
            }  
            @Override
            public String getValue(Data object) {
                return "";
            }
        };
```